# How do I merge .xps files?

Tags: xps, xpsdocument

Is there any way to combine multiple documents into on .xps file? I am hoping I can do this without having to install third party software. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is a [code sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd372938%28VS.85%29.aspx) demonstrating how to merge documents with the XPS Object Model in Windows 7.

Comment: Please do not only post link-only answers. If the link contains the answer, put the relevant part of the answer in your answer on StackOverflow. If the content behind the link changes, or the content is removed, your answer does not answer this question anymore.

Comment: And that is indeed what has happened.